# How to convert HTML to JSON using WSO2 Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I need to convert an HTML document to JSON using WSO2 Integration Studio. I'm not sure how to do this, and I'm looking for guidance on how to set up the conversion process and test it. Specifically, I'm wondering how to create a sequence that will convert the HTML document to JSON, and how to test the conversion using an API project in WSO2 Integration Studio. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to create a sequence in WSO2 Integration Studio that would convert an HTML document to JSON. Specifically, I involved creating a new sequence and adding a "Payload Factory" mediator to it.

Comment: The question doesn't have enough information to answer. Please add what you have already tried, a sample input, and the expected output format.